# JS/AJAX: submit without refresh or button clicking not firing after input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The js function will not work in my [SITE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/registration-form/) but when I try it in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/earlonrails/pXA6U/2/) it shows to work fine. I have included `DOM` ready  but it doesn't trigger anything. I checked with firefox and input value is not posted at all.  How can I get the JS function to fire up properly after user stops typing?

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 var timer = null; 
 var dataString;   
 function submitForm(){
   alert("success");
   $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result){
              alert("success");
               /*$('#special').append('<p>' +  $('#resultval', result).html() + '</p>');*/

            }

   });
   return false;
 }
 $('#submit').on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 2000);
    var name = $("#name").val();
    dataString = 'name='+ name;
 });
 }); 
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="field text medium" value="<? $url ?>" maxlength="255" tabindex="1"     />
```

Comment: use console.log() up see what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Have you tried setting a failure callback? If so what was the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the HTML above you have `id="name"` but are binding to `"#submit"`.

You have `id="submit"` in your jsfiddle example, which is why it works.

Comment: I thought it was being binded to the correct object. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On your site, I can't find an element with id "submit" so `$('#submit')` returns empty.